# Python3 converting bytestring

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary

So I am connecting to a IoT machine.

I have a bytestring

```
my_string = '\x01\x00\t\xd2\x01\x00\x01\x04keso\xcc'
```

Sending the string like this works perfect:

```
self._sock.send(b'\x01\x00\t\xd2\x01\x00\x01\x04keso\xcc')
```

but this fails

```
self._sock.send(my_string) #=> Error
#TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

so, my mission now is to get the string to be sent, and when i try to add my_string.encode(), then string will become `b'\x01\x00\t\xc3\x92\x01\x00\x01\x04keso\xc3\x8c'` which is not a correct representation, should be `b'\x01\x00\t\xd2\x01\x00\x01\x04keso\xcc'`

How the heck do I convert this?

Comment: `my_string` is not a byte string.

Comment: Ok, but regardless of that, it is what I have to work with. I cannot change that, its the only type of string that the iot device takes.

Comment: What? What do you mean it's the only type of string that the IOT device takes. What is creating this string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found it. It was using latin1 encoding.

Answer (score 0):

```py
my_string = '\x01\x00\t\xd2\x01\x00\x01\x04keso\xcc'
```

...is not a bytestring.
I think it should be ...

```py
my_string = b'\x01\x00\t\xd2\x01\x00\x01\x04keso\xcc'
```